# Calibration for pixels to real world unit

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am doing a project on parts inspection by measuring different geometric properties of an object([drill bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz6BX.jpg)) right now I am using a circle to calibrate from pixel to mm but since the [platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVazr.jpg) on which it is placed is at an angle of 20 degrees so now there is a lot of error. Is there another way of doing calibration for pixel to mm. I have done the camera calibration and I got the camera matrix, distance from the object to the camera is known, what else is required to get this calibration?

By the algorithm, I already tried when the platform is flat I am able to measure the total length(actual=120mm) of the [bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVmBp.jpg) to be 120mm +- 0.9mm but when the platform is angled it is difficult to get the accuracy of 0.01mm

I expect the output to be accurate to 1/10 mm but now I am getting a range from 1-1.5mm. A proper explanation with equation/code would be helpful

Comment: You should change the location of the camera to be perpendicular to the surface that both the drill bit and the dot are on.

Comment: What is algorithm you mentioned you are using? Any code you've written that you can share?

Comment: actually the code is simple I find otsu canny then using contour I calculate the no. of pixels in circle(1.3cm) which gives calibration for pixel to mm and I find the length of bit

Comment: if distance on pixel level, calibration and sensor size (in real world unit) are known, you can just compute the d positions of each pixel and measure 3d distances in real world units.

Comment: The vertical axis of the ellipse is seen in true size. The horizontal axis should be 94% of the former. But as the circle is slightly higher than the drill, perspective introduces a bias. You should account for this by placing the circle at various distances from the valley.

You can also calibrate using a drill of known diameter and relating the measured width to the size of the circle.

Comment: Micka what do you mean by distance on pixel level?

Comment: I meant it according to "distance from the object to the camera is known" do you have this distance fir each pixel or a single value per image? How accurate is that distance information?

Comment: I have the distance in single value per image, its up to 1mm.